TeX4ht doesn't generate correct footnote labels if I use standard footnotes and footnotes defined by manyfoot together
This question is a follow-up to TeX4ht doesn't work with bigfoot.
I would like to use the standard footnote command \footnote and a new level of footnotes defined by the package manyfoot together, and then generate an ebook using TeX4ht.
Using the solution from the original question, TeX4ht doesn't produce the correct footnote labels.
MWE
mwe.tex:
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{manyfoot}

\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[roman]

\begin{document}
    Hallooooooo.\footnote{first regular footnote}
    
    Bar.\footnoteB{some notes by translators}
    
    Foooooo.\footnote{second regular footnote}
    
    Baaaar.\footnoteB{some other notes by translators}
    
    \lipsum
    
    Hallooooooo.\footnote{third regular footnote}
    
    Foooooo.\footnote{fourth regular footnote}
    
    Bar.\footnoteB{some notes by translators on page 2}

    Baaaar.\footnoteB{some other notes by translators on page 2}
\end{document}

Compiled with:
$ tex4ebook -l mwe.tex -f epub3 "xhtml,fn-in"

Output
1. first regular footnote
i. some notes by translators
i. second regular footnote
ii. some other notes by translators
ii. third regular footnote
ii. fourth regular footnote
iii. some notes by translators on page 2
iv. some other notes by translators on page 2

Except for the first regular footnote, the other regular footnotes got a wrong label.
Desired Output
1. first regular footnote
i. some notes by translators
2. second regular footnote
ii. some other notes by translators
3. third regular footnote
4. fourth regular footnote
iii. some notes by translators on page 2
iv. some other notes by translators on page 2


Try this version of manyfoot-hooks.4ht:
% manyfoot-hooks.4ht (2024-11-17-21:56), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2024 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2024-11-17-21:56}


\:AtEndOfPackage{%
\let\o:MFL@declare:\MFL@declare

\def\manyfoot:declarefn#1{%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname footnote#1\endcsname[1]{%
    % save original footnote counters
    \let\:origthefootnote\thefootnote%
    \let\:origmpfn\@mpfn%
    \let\:origminipageNum\minipageNum%
    % \minipageNum is used in footnote links. we add the current suffix to produce unique links
    % if different footnote types use the same number
    \edef\minipageNum{\minipageNum #1}%
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\csname thefootnote#1\endcsname}%
    % declare which counter should be used
    \def\@mpfn{footnote#1}
    \footnote{##1}%
    \let\thefootnote\:origthefootnote%
    \let\@mpfn\:origmpfn%
    \let\minipageNum\:origminipageNum%
  }%
}

\def\MFL@declare#1#2[#3]{%
  \o:MFL@declare:{#1}{#2}[#3]%
  \manyfoot:declarefn{#2}%
}%


}

\endinput

There were two problems. The first was that we didn't restore the \thefootnote command after the modified footnote, so it printed normal footnotes in the style of \footnoteB. The second issue was that we call \footnote inside \footnoteB, and this increases the footnote counter in that case. So we must choose the right counter in the \@mpfn command. And to get correct links to footnotes, we will add a current command suffix to \minipageNum. This will create unique ID for each footnote, preventing duplicates if \foonote and \footnoteB use the same number.
This is the result:


Thanks! The labels are correct now but unfortunately the links are wrong: 2 goes to i; 3 goes to ii and iv goes to iii.

@texrob you are right. It should work correctly now.

I noticed that the last fix of the links introduced extra space before the footnote mark, like 'Bar. iii'. I fixed it by putting a % at the end of \def\@mpfn{footnote#1}.

@texrob you are right, thanks for spotting this. I will update TeX4ht sources.
